# Accepting Email Addresses in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have an .aspx page with static content and now want to a simple subscription system. I want to do the following on my page

1. Add a Submit button and a TextBox which accepts Email address (validation enabled). On clicking Submit, a message is sent with a link to the email address to Confirm subscription.
2. Once the user clicks on the link, his/her email gets registered in the database.

That's it. I am from php background and have been reading the Membership system, but have no clues what to do.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Start by adding a button to the form and handling the click event.  Google will help.  Once you've got that figured out, move onto the next step.  No-one's going to give you the entire solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the profile system to database associated info with username/password. Then you will send the email with a salted version of the hash. On receipt, you will perform the compare and confirmation.